# Firestore add data over an object within a document's data REACT.JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I want to add some data on the bookChapters object, like a random id and inside of it the name of the chapters, I tried this but it doesn't work, after I add the previous data I also want to add a new object "takeAways", like the previous one, inside the random id object.

[image]

```
export const createNewChapter = (bookId, inputText) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(createNewChapterStart());
    try {
firebase
        .firestore()
        .doc(`Users/${bookId}/bookChapters/${inputText}`)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          //There I want to add the chapters to the firestore database
        });
      dispatch(createNewChapterSuccess(inputText));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(createNewChapterFail(error));
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: I cannot see any code that related to updating data. Can you share a screenshot of your document and explain where you want to update/add data ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the image

Comment: BookChapters is not a collection. `.doc(\`Users/${bookId}/bookChapters/${inputText}\`)` should be `.doc(\`Users/${bookId}\`)`

Comment: I have 2 errors: 1) On the console   FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Users/ygWiDwAAQBAJ has 2.

Comment: 2) querySnapshot.forEach is not a function

Comment: For 1: are you sure you used `.doc()` and not `.collection()` and bookId is defined? It returns a documentSnapshot. Remove the forEach and log `console.log(snapshot.data())`

Comment: The code in your question shows how you would read the chapters from the map (the `bookChapters` field). But how do you want to populate/initialize this field? Do you have a list of chapters? Are you sure the keys shall be totally random? No chapter order?

Comment: I receive an inputText so I add that every time I don't have a list, It true I can use a numerate order for all the chapters

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have to delete both the forEach loop? and do ```console.log(querySnapshot.data())```

Comment: Ok, what is your exact question then? :) The question's title says "Firestore add data over an object" but you seem to know how to add the data... ?

Comment: Yes remove everything in `onSnapshot` and add log statement. A document snapshot is single doc and not array of documents.

Comment: No, I don't know how to add data on the bookChapters object

Comment: "No, I don't know how to add data on the bookChapters object" => What is the source? You have a JavaScript array containing the chapters?

Comment: I added the console image to the question

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I updated the code whit all the functions

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do and where you encounter difficulties. You write "I want to add some data on the bookChapters object, like a random id and inside of it the name of the chapters, I tried this but it doesn't work" Based on your code, I understand that you want to use the data stored in the `inputText` variable. Can you give an example of value for `inputText`? Is it a simple string (you do use it in a string literal `Users/${bookId}/bookChapters/${inputText}`) or an array (it seems a book has several chapters)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec inputText is a string that the user writes, the book can have several chapters, but is based on the user, he can add one chapters but if he wants also 100 chapters

Comment: But if `inputText` is a string, `chaptersList.push({ key: k, name: inputText });` will generate an array of objects which all have the same value for `name`... Also, if `doc.data().bookChapters` is empty, the `Object.keys(chapters).forEach` loop will not do anything  => we come back to the question on how do you want to populate/initialize this `bookChapters` field (source data and business logic)

Comment: The code I probably wrong, I only wanna know how to do add from scratch the bookChapters object, and how to add  inside of it, all the numbered chapters object, where inside I can also add the title of the chapters (inputText) and the new takeAways Object

Comment: I'm sorry for my horrible English

Comment: If you don't understand tell me only how to add on bookId document an object (bookChapters) with inside other objects

Comment: See the answer. Not sure is exactly what you are looking for... Also, where do you want to add the new `takeAways` Object?? Within the `bookChapters`object? Or as a new field of the document?

Comment: I had what I want thanks and sorry for the incomprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanna know how to do add from scratch the bookChapters object

The database screenshot shows that the `bookChapters` object is a map. So to add (populate) this object you need to generate a simple JavaScript object with some properties as “key: value” pairs.

Something along these lines, making the assumption the chapter titles are in an Array:

```
  function arrayToObject(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      obj[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return obj;
  }

  const chapterList = ['Intro', 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter2', 'Conclusion'];
  const bookChaptersObj = arrayToObject(chapterList);

  firebase.firestore().doc(`Users/${bookId}`).update(bookChaptersObj);
```

Or, if the document does not already exist:

```
firebase.firestore().doc(`Users/${bookId}`).set(bookChaptersObj, {merge: true});
```

Comment: I have this error: TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function, how can I resolve it? I've just updated the code on the latest answear

Comment: This is normal: with `firebase.firestore().doc(`Users/${bookId}`)` you define a `DocumentReference`, not a `Query`. So when you set the listener with `onSnapshot`, the argument passed to the anonymous function  is a `DocumentSnapshot` (and not a `QuerySnapshot`), and a `DocumentSnapshot` does not have a `forEach()` method. I don't exactly understand what you want to do with "Storing the old chapters from firestore"... You may explain with some diagrams or screenshots (before/after) what is your exact goal, because it is not clear to me.